# Embedded mapping for ember-data with ember-app-kit

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-app-kit

I'm trying to create an embedded mapping as described in the docs. However I can't seem to get it to work. I'm struggling to get the instance of my adapter so I can run the `map()` function. Here's what I have so far

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true,
  LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
  modulePrefix: 'appkit', // TODO: loaded via config
  Resolver: Resolver,
  Router: Ember.Router.extend({
    router: router
  }),
  Store: DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: adapter
  })
});

//App.Store.adapter.map('transaction', {
//  'entries': {embedded: 'always'}
//});
```

What's the correct code for the actual mapping? (entry and transaction are two models).

Comment: What part of the docs are you looking at?  I'm not finding anything about `map()`...

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_embedded-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the data on the main Ember site about embedded records is out of date.  The Ember Data TRANSITION document describes the new way to handle embedded records.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#embedded-records

Comment: thanks for the heads up. Unfortunately the solution they give seems to work if you're using the RESTAdapter, but I'm not sure how you'd apply this to the FixtureAdapter.